# Motivation of Puiseux's Riemann surface and Galois group theory

Tags: mathematics-social-history, riemannian-geometry, galois-theory

If you look at Felix Klein's "Development of mathematics in the 19th century", it says that Puiseux developed the Riemann surface theory to show the connection between the two Galois groups.

> We saw how the Riemann surface is connected with the ideas of Galois theory, as long as we specify the basic parameter $z$ of the field, and how the ideas of Galois theory can be made intuitive with the help of Riemann surface. Instead of giving the Riemann surface. I can prescribe the branch places $a,b,...,k$ and stipulate which permutations arise from the continuations along closed paths. this takes us from Riemann back to Pulseux, who brought forward such groups in 1851. But this contains the amazing possibility of carrying over to number fields, not the Riemann surface itself but the theorems and questions that follow from considering it. For the branch places $a,b,...,k$ correspond, as we already know, to the prime factors of the "essential" component of the discriminant, and the Galois group of the algebraic function field naturally corresponds to the Galois group of the number field. **(Development of mathematics in the 19th century p.313~314)**

And I saw this [file.](https://hal.science/hal-01674509/document) if you see this file's page 8,

> We showed that Puiseux studied how the fact that the roots of an algebraic equation are interchanged when the variable $z$ describes some loops in the plane leads to a group factorized into permutations. He used in this context the word “monodromic,” which was already introduced by Cauchy. Hermite continued using this word in [37] (1851).10 This led eventually to the notion of monodromy group, which we still use today. Jordan, in his Trait´e des substitutions [40] (1870), defined a group he called the algebraic group, which contains the monodromy group as a normal subgroup. The paper [37] by Hermite in which he studies the solvability
> of equations by radicals makes the relation between the work of Puiseux and the
> Galois group of an algebraic equation. Hermite’s paper starts as follows

Could you explain the motivation and mathematical background for Puiseux's work focusing on the relationship between the Riemann surface and the Galois group?

Comment: Is this associated with covering space?